# Is earning through the foreign exchange market (forex) halal?

Tags: halal-haram, riba, money, business

[Foreign exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_exchange_market) involves trading of different currencies in order to make a profit. Does the additional amount count as interest or is it halal?

Comment: Answer from a Shia perspective: http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa7782

Answer from a Sunni Salafi perspective: https://islamqa.info/en/106094

Comment: Jazakallah Khair!